# Object Literal Shorthand Syntax. Is trailing comma required?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm going through [react-redux boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate)

there is a code there

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}
```

I wondered why a comma after dispatch is required?
i.e. when i remove comma eslint hints an error:

Insert ',' eslint(prettier/prettier)

I played it with babeljs.io either with/without comma the code is converted into

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch: dispatch
  };
}
```

It does not matter a lot but to understand why eslint forces me to put the comma..

Comment: It's just a convention/opinion set in the project you are re-using. It is not required.

Comment: Just to be clear: It's required by an ESLint rule. It's **not** required by JavaScript syntax. (It's *allowed* by JavaScript syntax as of ES5.)

Answer (score 2):

See [the ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle):

> Trailing commas simplify adding and removing items to objects and arrays, since only the lines you are modifying must be touched. Another argument in favor of trailing commas is that it improves the clarity of diffs when an item is added or removed from an object or array: